# stream edit >GDRLR5L04EQY8D 3931|1166 into >3931

Tags: text-processing

I have large text DNA sequence files with the following format

```
>name 
AACTGGGCT
```

I need to parse the name line which currently has extra information and special characters, while keeping any line that doesn't start with > unaltered

have (that is a tab not a space between "D 3"):

```
>GDRLR5L04EQY8D 3931|1166
GACAAACGCTGGCGGGTGCATGAG
```

want:

```
>3931
GACAAACGCTGGCGGGTGCATGAG
```

I've tried `sed 's/\>*[[:blank:]]/>/g'` to get rid of the first part but that's not working.  Would `gawk` work to get rid of the pipe and number after it?

Comment: The awk suggestion worked while the sed suggestions didn't.  I'm running ubuntu 12.04 (I know it's old but I'm not updating till I get a major project off my plate).  I'd appreciate ideas of why the sed one liners aren't working

Comment: edited the question because it is a tab not a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'[| ]' '{if ( $1 ~ /^>/ ) print ">"$2; else print $0}' file
>3931
GACAAACGCTGGCGGGTGCATGAG
```

If the whitespace between the end of the first string and the beginning of the set of digits before the pipe is a <kbd>Tab</kbd>, not a <kbd>Space</kbd>, the regex to set the field delimiter would be `[|\t]`.

Comment: Ok so I understand this.  [| ] is giving space and pipe as field deliminators? ($1 ~ /^>/) is first field starts with >?

Comment: @thermophile Yes, that is correct. :)

Comment: oh it was a tab, not a space.  changed to [|\t] and now have the correct output

Comment: @thermophile updated to reflect that info

Answer (score 2):

sed solution:

```
sed '/^>/s/>.* \([0-9]*\)|.*/>\1/' < existing-file > new-file
```

Note that `/^>/` causes the command following it to operate only on the input lines that begin with >, something that you seemed to not know `sed` could do.

Comment: Made some suggested fixes: the braces weren't needed, and you were stripping the `>` from the start of the line.

Comment: This isn't altering the file

Comment: @thermophile sed reads from standard input and writes to standard output, so the usual shell i/o redirection will work.  I've edited the answer to show how to do this.

Comment: done that, the new file is being created but is identical to the old

Comment: @thermophile Well, I can only guess that the parsing required is more than the single example you gave us suggests.

Comment: @thermophile Add `-i` to edit the files in place.  In which case you can replace  `< existing-file > new-file` with `existing-file`.

Comment: I copied and pasted one of the sequences as my example, it is exactly what I'm trying to edit. awk worked, I'd like to understand why sed isn't but if it's just not the tool for the job-that's fine

Comment: @thermophile You mentioned that the line contained a tab character.  That certainly would cause the code above to fail.  It expects a space before the strings of digits, not a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed`:

```
$ sed -e 's/[^>].* \([0-9]*\)|.*/\1/' file
>3931
GACAAACGCTGGCGGGTGCATGAG
```

Comment: getting an error "sed: -e expression #1, char 25: Invalid back reference"

Comment: What command did you run?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/>.* />/;s/|.*//
' <<\DATA
>GDRLR5L04EQY8D 3931|1166
GACAAACGCTGGCGGGTGCATGAG
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
>3931
GACAAACGCTGGCGGGTGCATGAG
```

Comment: not getting the same output, it's only removing the pipe and the following numbers    >GDRLR5L04EQY8D 3931

Comment: @thermophile - you copy+pasted it exactly? Is the space maybe not a space in your file - maybe it is a tab?

Comment: copy and pasted and typed it too.  I'm pretty sure it's a space, but what should be changed if it's a tab?

Comment: @thermophile - just do `sed -n l file` - you'lll know after. If it is a tab then you just need to change the space to a tab. Still, I'm not sure that's what it is.

Comment: It's not removing the stuff after the pipe, right?

Comment: it isn't altering the file at all

Comment: then it is spaces. I don't know why it doesn't work. As you can see - I copy+pasted your example entry into an input file and provided the command with input file complete. Wait... you are removing the `<<\DATA...DATA` bit right?